# How to set auto width of Excel columns using axlsx gem in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

Is there a way to set the column width to adjust based on the text length for all the columns in an excel (that is generated using the axlsx gem in Ruby on rails)? Please help!

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far?

Comment: `ws.column_widths 7.2, nil, 3` can be parameterized.

Comment: Setting ws.column_widths to nil will make the widths auto adjustable?

Comment: No it won't.  Need to figure out from that API